# How to hide Id paramter from link in asp.net core MVC jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

here is my script where i am redirecting to my view

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.btndetail', function () {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var url = "/Schools/SchoolDetails/Id=" + id;
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    );
</script>
```

and id comes in COntroller

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult SchoolDetails(string Id)
 {
     return View();
 }
```

> http://localhost:55696/Schools/SchoolDetails/Id=1234

But Id is showing in a link how can i hide it ?

Comment: Why do you want to "hide" the parameter? You will always have to send the Id with the request your making. What you could use if you dont want to let the user see the id is to encode it. For example with JWT (https://jwt.io/)

Comment: You can make SEO friendly strings for school names. Like `Some International School` to `Some-international-school`. And get details of related school. As you are showing school details, no worry in showing name in url.

Comment: Use ajax calls with post method

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the value to be shown you'll have to post it to the server.

If you don't want the page to refresh, you'll do a POST with ajax and only update a part of the page. This can be achieved with the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btndetail', function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var url = "/Schools/SchoolDetails/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: { Id: id },
            success: function (data) {
                //returns whatever your controller returns.
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //error
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Your controller would also have to be updated to expect this "POST"

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SchoolDetails(string Id)
{
    return View();
}
```

If you want to post and redirect the user to that posted page - you can use a neat free jQuery plugin called [jQuery.Redirect](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect)

```
$(document).on('click', '.btndetail', function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var url = "/Schools/SchoolDetails/";

        $.redirect(url, {
                Id: id
        });

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the ajax method, to make asynchronous calls with GET, see this document:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Here is an example to implement in your code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btndetail', function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var url = '@Url.Action("SchoolDetails", "Schools")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: { Id = id },
            success: function (data) {
                // Success Here
                window.location.href = url;

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        })
    })
```